# How to parse i64 from a string?

Tags: rust

Apparently, something has changed and thus I can't parse i64 from string:

```
use std::from_str::FromStr;

let tree1: BTreeMap<String, String> = //....
let my_i64: i64 = from_str(tree1.get("key1").unwrap().as_slice()).unwrap();
```

Error:

```
16:27 error: unresolved import `std::from_str::FromStr`. Could not find `from_str` in `std`

$ rustc -V
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (4be79d6ac 2015-01-23 16:08:14 +0000)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your import fails because the `FromStr` trait is now [`std::str::FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html). Also, [`from_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html#tymethod.from_str) is no longer in the `prelude`. The preferred way to convert strings to integers is [`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse)

```
fn main() {
    let i = "123".parse::<i64>();
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

prints

```
Ok(123)
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20i%20%3D%20%22123%22.parse%3A%3A%3Ci64%3E%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20i%29%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: Use `let i: i64 = "123".parse();` instead of ugly template syntax if possible.

Comment: @hauleth, `.parse()` returns `Option<T>`, so that would have to be `let i: Option<i64> = "123".parse();`.

Comment: Yes. Of course. I've forgotten.

Comment: update: nowadays it returns `Result<F, <F as FromStr>::Err>` so simple `.parse()` won't work, or am I wrong?

Comment: @KeeperHood A simple parse will still work; you just need to handle the error like you used to handle the `Option`.